# Is there a light source of some sort in 2D Animation workspace default file?

Tags: lighting, 2d

When a new 2D Animation file was created, I noticed that unlike general workspace, the whole background looks bright white. Meanwhile, there was no light source in collection. The way I understand it is that essentially, we need light source while rendering, or we won't see jack. Yet in 2D animation, the world is lit without an obvious light source in the collection, and I can render my animation without worrying about light problems.

I wanna know what makes 2D animation special? Was it some sort of settings that I don't know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are totally right. If you go to Shader editor and change to "world", you will see:

[image]

And this is "different" to "other" workspaces. If you change the strength of the background you will see the color change.

[image]

and this is how the "normal 3D" world shader looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this solves my issue! Have a nice day!

Comment: Thank you and dito!